# SQL using todays date for search

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using a custom report designer in a CRM program called ACT. I'm having trouble finding a way to use today's date as a criteria other than typing it in manually.

```
SELECT CONTACT.Product,
  CONTACT.Company,
  CONTACT.Contact,
  CONTACT.[Brochure Sent Tick],
  CONTACT.[Edit Date],
  CONTACT.[Create Date]
FROM CONTACT
WHERE CONTACT.[Brochure Sent Tick] = 'FALSE' AND CONTACT.[Create Date] = '11/06/2015'
```

Is there a way function that could be used? As each time this query is ran it should only look at the day its ran and not a date specified.

Comment: CURRENT_DATE is the ANSI SQL way, don't know if MySQL supports it.

Comment: BTW, are you really using MySQL? [column] indicates something else...

Comment: Sorry the dialect was set to MS SQL The query builder within this software package is very confusing.. I'm normally use to using mysql for my php work.

Comment: Actually I think both MS SQL Server and MySQL have CURRENT_DATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GETDATE()` will give you the current date **and** time. Cast it to `date` to get the date only:

```
SELECT CONTACT.Product,
  CONTACT.Company,
  CONTACT.Contact,
  CONTACT.[Brochure Sent Tick],
  CONTACT.[Edit Date],
  CONTACT.[Create Date]
FROM CONTACT
WHERE CONTACT.[Brochure Sent Tick] = 'FALSE'
AND CONTACT.[Create Date] = CAST(GETDATE() as date)
```

Comment: I've put test data in for today's date and its still not returning anything.

Comment: What's the data type of the `[Create Date]` column? `Date` and `varchar` behave differently.

Comment: Its a system field which im guessing is a date/time data type but I can't find due to the Database on ACT! being locked.

Answer (score 1):

In Sql Server you can use `GETDATE()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to return the current system DateTime. If you just want the date, you can cast it:

```
CAST(GETDATE() AS Date)
```

If you have problem mapping to the date format you're using, `dd/mm/yyyy`, try specifying the convert type to format the date correctly:

```
CONVERT(Date, GETDATE() , 103)
```

This will use the British/French standard (103) of `dd/mm/yyyy`.
You might even need to cast it to a `varchar`, if this is what you use in `[Create Date]`:

```
CAST(CONVERT(Date, GETDATE() , 103) AS varchar(10))
```